# Xrm.Navigation is undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to open a modal dialog box,  and I write:

```
var addParams = "entityid=" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() + "&entityName=" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
var webresourceurl = "/webresources/pdfflr_selectorpage.html?Data=" + encodeURIComponent(addParams);
var parameters = {};
parameters["width"] = parent.document.body.clientWidth * 0.95;
parameters["top"] = '0px';
parameters["left"] = '0px';
parameters["height"] = parent.document.body.clientHeight;
//!!!           
Xrm.Utility.openDialog(webresourceurl, parameters, null, null, null);
```

I have to rewrite `Xrm.Utility.openDialog` to `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource` or something like this, but here `Xrm.Navigation is undefined`.

How can I open a dialog box with `Xrm.Navigation`?

Comment: You have tagged this as both CRM 2011 and Dynamics 365 v9. Which version are you actually running?

Comment: 2011 version. thank you

Comment: Sorry, Dynamics 365 !

Comment: Is this the same as this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972516/method-xrm-utility-opendialog-is-deprecated-but-why

Answer (score 1):

[`Xrm.Navigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation) has been introduced with Dynamics 365 v9. See [Some client APIs are deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated).

For CRM 2011 `Xrm.Navigation` does not exist. Instead you should use [`Xrm.Utility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developers-guide/jj602956(v=crm.5)).

Comment: So,  2011 CRM means version 8.2, but 2013 CRM means 9 version?

Comment: No. 2011=v5, 2013=v6, 2015=v7, 2016=v8, D365=8.2/9

Comment: Microsoft says:
"XRM.Utility.opendialog () is an internal method ,External Usage of opendialog is not supported . Please come up with an alternate solution for this" so I can't use Xrm.Utility ! :(

Comment: Yes, Xrm.Navigation should exist in Dynamics 365 v9. It apparently does not work in Dynamics 365 8.2 (i.e. if you are on-premises). It is not clear to my why you are talking about .openDialog. In your question you are trying to use .openWebResource, which is supported by both Xrm.Utility and Xrm.Navigation. I will let you take it from here.

Comment: I understand! Thank you! I should not use only method "opendialog",  but i can use Xrm.Utility. So,  can You advice me a method, which i can use instead "openDialog" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource) for `openWebResource` for Dynamics 365 (v9+)

**Modal** dialogs aren't really supported anymore. You can open a **non**-modal browser window using `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource`

Here's your code transformed:

```
var data = {};
data["entityid"] = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
data["entityName"] = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

var options = {};
options["width"] = parent.document.body.clientWidth * 0.95;
options["top"] = '0px';
options["left"] = '0px';
options["height"] = parent.document.body.clientHeight;

Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource("pdfflr_selectorpage.html", options, JSON.stringify(data));
```

Note:

- Don't need to include `"/webresources"` in your URL
- Don't need to include the querystring arguments in your url. There is a `data` parameter