# Method Xrm.Utility.openDialog is deprecated, but why?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Method `Xrm.Utility.openDialog()` is deprecated, but I can't find any information about this method, and any alternative for this?

Can you help me to find alternative method for `openDialog()`?

Comment: Dynamics CRM 8.2

Comment: Was it ever a function? It's not listed on the MSDN? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Dialogues in Dynamics CRM are deprecated. It makes sense that any other dependent code would be to.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there has never been a function called `Xrm.Utility.openDialog()`.

A few years ago developers used `window.showModalDialog()` to open custom modal windows from within Dynamics CRM. However, popular browsers like Chrome stopped supporting this function, which had been an IE invention anyway. Modal dialogs block access to the main opening window and harm user experience on tablets and smart phone interfaces, so nowadays they are considered to be a bad design choice.

As an alternative some Dynamics CRM developers started using the internal function `Xrm.Internal.openDialog()`. Nevertheless this function has never been part of the supported API and should not be used.

An alternative would be to inject een IFrame at the end of the body of the page and display your dialog in it. This is the way built-in Dynamics CRM dialogs currently are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft told me what I must use Xrm.Utility.openWebResource() method.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

we have a custom ribbon button that runs a dialog on demand using JavaScript. This is a snippet of the code that you may find useful. We do not use `.openDialog()`.

```
window.open(
    Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId="
    + encodeURIComponent(DIALOG_ID)
    + "&EntityName=new_entityname&ObjectId=" + encodeURIComponent(ENTITY_ID),
    "formRibbon_runDialog_" + DIALOG_ID + "_" + ENTITY_ID,
    "height=480, width=615"
);
```

It is also worth noting that Dialogs in general are deprecated by Microsoft, but it will likely be many years until they are truly removed from the system so it's not much to worry about.

Let me know if you have any questions.